# If-condition based on standard output

Tags: scripting, stdout

I have few commands linked through pipes, and at the end is a conditional `awk`: example below

```
command1 | command 2 | awk '$1 > 800'
```

Now sometimes it will output few lines, and sometimes no lines.
I want a condition that will prove true only if there's some output (1 or more lines)
Is there a way to make it work?

Like,

```
if command1 | command 2 | awk '$1 > 800' (some output); then
do command3
else; (blank output)
Do nothing
```

Comment: You could pipe the output into a `while read` construct. The while loop will iterate once for every line of output. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally just use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), then put it in a test, e.g.

```
if [ ! -z "$(command1 | command 2 | awk '$1 > 800')" ]; then command3; fi
```

### Explanation

- This runs the command as per your question: `command1 | command 2 | awk '$1 > 800'`
- The output of this is passed to the test `[ ! -z "$(…)" ]`, which will be true if it is not `!` a string of zero length `-z`.

Hence, if there is output to the command pipe, the `then` commands will run.

Comment: Thanks @Sparhawk that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `awk` script exit with the correct return code for your `if` statement:

```
if command1 | command2 | awk '$1 > 800 { c++; print } END { exit (c == 0) }'
then
   command3
fi
```

Or, if you don't actually *need* the output of the `awk` program:

```
if command1 | command2 | awk '$1 > 800 { c++; exit } END { exit (c == 0) }'
then
   command3
fi
```

Comment: Could c wrap (or is awk arbitrary precision)?

Comment: Note that that `exit` would close the pipe and potentially cause `command2` to be killed with SIGPIPE (which may or may not be desired)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, `awk` typically uses `long` C compiler type for its integers which will generally be 64bit. It would take years for that number to wrap.

Comment: My computer can do in a month, what would have taken millions of years in 1970. So if Mores law continues, millions of years is less than 50 years away.

Answer (score 0):

You can let `awk` print the desired exit code, like this:

```
echo 900 | awk '{ print !($1 > 800) }'
```

Then this can be wrapped in a subshell using `(` and `exit`, for returning the value from `awk`:

```
echo 900 | (exit $(awk '{ print !($1 > 800) }'))
```

Which can then be used as part of a pipeline:

```
echo 900 | (exit $(awk '{ print !($1 > 800) }')) && echo yes || echo no
```